# Java Executequery Hangs

Tags: java, jdbc

I'm executing a very simple SQL, that when I run in SQL Server Management Studio it's take a few seconds.
But when I run in java using JDBC it freezes. The memory usage goes from 34MB to 280MB.

```
public int size() {
    int lines = 0;
    string StringSize = "SELECT COUNT(BO_Numseq) FROM dbo.BOLETO";
    try {
        Statement statementL = connection.createStatement();
        ResultSet rsLocal = statementL.executeQuery(StringSize);
        rsLocal.next();
        int size = rsLocal.getInt(1);
        resetConnexion();
        return size;
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(ModelTratamentoBoleto.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    return lines;

public void resetConnexion() {
    try {

        connection = MSFConstants.controleur.getConnectionAutomat().getCnx();
        statement = connection.createStatement();
        rs = statement.executeQuery(stringCommand);
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(ModelTratamentoBoleto.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}



public class ConnectionAutomat {

private Connection cnx;
private String stringConnection;

public ConnectionAutomat() {
//           System.out.println("start ConnectionAutomat");
    MSFConstants.versionBdD = "NV02.06c";
    String sysUserName = System.getProperty("user.name");
    String activeBase="Automat";
    if(MSFConstants.SWtestSandBox){
        activeBase="AutomatSandbox";
    }
        stringConnection = "jdbc:sqlserver://localhost;"
                + "databaseName="+activeBase+";user="
                + MSFConstants.user.getLogonAutomat()
                + ";password="
                + MSFConstants.user.getPassAutomat();
    }

//        System.out.println("ConnectionAutomat stringConnection " + stringConnection);
    try {
        cnx = DriverManager.getConnection(stringConnection);
//     System.out.println("ConnectionAutomat connection");
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
//              System.out.println("ConnectionAutomat erreur");
        javax.swing.JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                "Error ");
//            Logger.getLogger(ConnectionAutomat.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        MSFConstants.controleur.fermetureApplication();
    }




}

public Connection getCnx() {
    return cnx;
}
```

It hangs in the line "ResultSet rsLocal = statementL.executeQuery(StringSize);"

I'm running this jar on Java Update 8 25, so I don't think it's version problem.

Important information is it was running perfectly till last week and nothing was changed in the code.

What can I do to make this work? I'm completely lost and don't know java very well.

Thank you!

Comment: There are identifiers here like `StringSize` and `resetConnexion()` which you haven't shown us the code for, so we don't know what they do.

Comment: Fix that. Sorry!
But it freezes at the line "ResultSet rsLocal = statementL.executeQuery(StringSize);" so never reachs resetConnexion()

Comment: You might uppercase the `String` type

Comment: Alright.  Let's see the code for `connection` as well.  And `statementL`.  Did you really mean `statement`?

Comment: The code is here now. The stranger thing is that until last week it was working and NOTHING was changed in the code.
About the statement, I guess I mean it. The code it's not mine, I'm not a Java programmer but the developer it's not here anymore and I'm trying to fix it. See the drama? :(

Comment: code is still incomplete, stringCommand used in resetConnexion() is not defined

Comment: most likely you have some sort of recursion going on. why do you need resetConnexion() at all? call to this method should be most probably removed.

Comment: But why need the resetConnexion() if it never be reached? It freezes at "ResultSet rsLocal = statementL.executeQuery(StringSize)";

Comment: Your statement may have not changed, perhaps the database has a lot more rows now? Or the DB server has some issues. Anyway try to enable JDBC debug logging and see what that says.

Comment: Yes, a lot of more rows this week. The DB has changed.
Sorry for the silly question, but how do I enable it?

Answer (score -1):

It seems to be more of a data issue. Try analyzing that table from DB side and run your code again.

Comment: Its a possibility. But how a data can freezes and use high memory usage of my code? All the rows have size limit, so they are small.